# How to get dates on the xaxis of my Arima forecast plot rather than just numbers

Tags: r, arima

I have imported a netCDF file into R and created a dataset which has 58196 time stamps. I’ve then fitted an Arima model to it and forecasted. However, the format of the time is ‘hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00’. Each of the times are just in a numerical order up to 58196, but I would like to use ggplot to plot the forecast with dates on the xaxis.

Any ideas? Here is some code I have put in.

I have read in the required variable and taken it along what pressure level I want, so that it is a single variable at 58169 times, 6hourly intervals up to the end of the year in 2018. I have then done the following:

```
    data <- data_array[13, ] # To get my univariate time series.

    print(data)

    [58176] -6.537371e-01 -4.765177e-01 -4.226107e-01 -4.303621e-01 
    -3.519134e-01
    [58181] -2.706966e-01 -1.864843e-01 -9.974014e-02  2.970415e-02  
    6.640909e-02
    [58186] -1.504763e-01 -3.968417e-01 -4.864971e-01 -5.934973e-01 
    -7.059880e-01
    [58191] -7.812654e-01 -7.622807e-01 -8.968482e-01 -9.414597e-01 
    -1.003678e+00
    [58196] -9.908477e-01

    datafit <- auto.arima(data)

    datamodel <- Arima(data, order = c(5, 0, 2))

    datafcst <- forecast(datamodel, h=60, level=95)                                    
    plot(datafcst, xlim=c(58100, 58250))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXFz8.png)

I have attached the image it yields too. The idea is that I can use ggplot to plot this rather than the standard plot, with dates on the xaxis instead of the numerical values. However, ggplot also won't work for me as it says it isn't considered a data frame?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509002/converting-numeric-time-to-datetime-posixct-format-in-r

Answer (score 0):

as you did not provide a minimal example it is hard to help you but I try. Assume your date is called "date".

dater = as.Date(strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))

And from ?strptime: 
format
A character string. The default for the format methods is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" if any element has a time component which is not midnight, and "%Y-%m-%d" otherwise.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I have attached some more code at the top which hopefully may help. If I could alter each numeric to a date and figure out how to plot in ggplot, that would be great.

Comment: You still miss sample Data in your Code, but you should try to adopt the code snipped I posted and than ggplot does the job for you! :)

Comment: Okay thanks. So do I just specify this as dates and then do ggplot(data)? I tried this last time and it said it couldn't do it as it needed a data frame

Comment: Yes you need to put all data you wanna plot in a dataframe. For you this would work e.g. like this:    

   `data frame <- data.frame( datafcst,youtimevariable )`  after you seted the time variable right.           With ggplot you would do sth like 'ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = yourtimevar , y = datafcst) +
  geom_point()`

Comment: Great cheers! I included some sample data, above. So using the as.Date I can just edit the numeric dates to actual dates and then execute into a dataframe like that?

Comment: Hey this is still not a workable minimal example but I think you can put together your solution with my edited comment above.